# Travis: Can you construct env var using other env vars?

Tags: environment-variables, travis-ci

What I'm looking to do is setup my travis.yml to use the appropriately named environment vars based on which branch is being built.

I'm thinking along the lines of, if I have stored in travis $DEV_ARTIFACTS_KEY / $TEST_ARTIFACTS_KEY etc

Then I push to DEV branch, so $TRAVIS_BRANCH = DEV

I can then do something like: ARTIFACTS_KEY=${$TRAVIS_BRANCH}_ARTIFACTS_KEY
and it becomes: ARTIFACTS_KEY=$DEV_ARTIFACTS_KEY

Obviously the above syntax with {} doesn't work, or I wouldn't be here! Wondering whether in theory this method is possible, and if so, how!?

EDIT: For further detail on what I'm trying to do

I'm wanting to set 3 variables in the above manner.

ARTIFACTS_KEY, ARTIFACTS_SECRET & ARTIFACTS_BUCKET created on the fly from
{BRANCH}_ARTIFACTS_KEY, {BRANCH}_ARTIFACTS_SECRET, {BRANCH}_ARTIFACTS_BUCKET

I have it working without the branch variables like:

```
env:
  - ARTIFACTS_KEY=$DEV_ARTIFACTS_KEY ARTIFACTS_SECRET=$DEV_ARTIFACTS_SECRET ARTIFACTS_BUCKET=$DEV_ARTIFACTS_BUCKET
```

where $DEV_ARTIFACTS_KEY etc are defined in Travis. However I've so far failed at replacing the DEV portion with a branch name on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

This works in bash and therefore should also work in Travis:

```bash
# setup dummy values
TRAVIS_BRANCH=DEV
DEV_ARTIFACTS_KEY=dev-artifacts-key-value
DEV_ARTIFACTS_SECRET=dev-artifacts-secret-value
DEV_ARTIFACTS_BUCKET=dev-artifacts-bucket-value

# actual lines you want
eval ARTIFACTS_KEY=\$${TRAVIS_BRANCH}_ARTIFACTS_KEY
eval ARTIFACTS_SECRET=\$${TRAVIS_BRANCH}_ARTIFACTS_SECRET
eval ARTIFACTS_BUCKET=\$${TRAVIS_BRANCH}_ARTIFACTS_BUCKET

# test results
echo "key=$ARTIFACTS_KEY"
echo "secret=$ARTIFACTS_SECRET"
echo "bucket=$ARTIFACTS_BUCKET"
```

Whenever you have the name of a variable inside another variable, you need `eval` to interpret it. When bash sees this line:

```bash
eval ARTIFACTS_KEY=\$${TRAVIS_BRANCH}_ARTIFACTS_KEY
```

It first expands the variable (and leaves the escaped `$` alone):

```bash
eval ARTIFACTS_KEY=\$DEV_ARTIFACTS_KEY
```

Then it executes `eval` on the string `ARTIFACTS_KEY=$DEV_ARTIFACTS_KEY` which in turn expands `$DEV_ARTIFACTS_KEY` and assigns the value to `ARTIFACTS_KEY`.

Comment: ooh, this is closer, though still not quite working. It is now evaluating the TRAVIS_BRANCH correctly, but then looks to be treating the resulting value as a string rather than another environment variable. So, besides the ARTIFACTS_KEY I'm also trying to set ARTIFACTS_BUCKET & in the logging it's saying "bucket: $DEV_ARTIFACTS_BUCKET" rather than my actual bucket name. Is it possible to have the resulting value treated as an env var, or am I trying to do the impossible?

Comment: This code, when executed in bash, *should* assign the value of `$DEV_ARTIFACTS_BUCKET` to `ARTIFACTS_KEY`. I did not test it on Travis though. But you seem to be doing something else you did not mention previously (`ARTIFACTS_BUCKET`), care to update the question?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, have updated question to include all variables I'm trying to set :)

Comment: Updated answer.